Header and footer with landscape
I try to apply fancyhdr package with landscape pages, but it works incorrect.
Need some help to figure things out.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L, R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{\footnotesize I like sky}
\fancyfoot[L, C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
    \section{One}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{One One}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \newgeometry{,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm,landscape}
    
    \lipsum[3-5]
    
    \restoregeometry
    \lipsum[6]
    
\end{document}



Try \fancyhfoffset{0pt}

@PietervanOostrum Thank you! That's work fine.
